# Creating sqlite3 database from .sql file in Windows 8

Tags: python, sql, windows, sqlite, flask

I'm using [this tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/dbinit/) for learning flask. In the second paragraph it says to use this command:

```
sqlite3 /tmp/flaskr.db < schema.sql
```

But I'm using Windows 8. What can I do instead of that command? This is my sql code:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    title text not null,
    text text not null
);
```

Comment: I think this is sqlite3.exe. So you can call it with parameters from your Cmd. But maybe a bit different

Comment: no i cant use this command in sqlite3. i tested it. can you tell it how can i call it from cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep following the tutorial by adding the init_db method and running the following python script:

```
# all the imports
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask
from contextlib import closing

# configuration
DATABASE = './flaskr.db'
DEBUG = True


# create our little application :)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init_db()
    #app.run()
```

to make it simple, database file *flaskr.db* will be created in the current directory and *schema.sql* is supposed to be there too ...

Comment: thank you very much.this script worked for me. but let me ask 2 questions:can i add SECRET_KEY and USERNAME and PASSWORD to this script?what is the difference between this script and using .read schema.sql and save it as flaskr.db on sqlite3.exe?

Comment: yes you can add the other fields such as SECRET_KEY, USERNAME in the script and it has the same effect as running sqlite3 flaskr.db < schema.sql so you don't really need the commandline ...